# Xcode Undefined symbol: std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const

Tags: xcode, symbols

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"std::__1::__vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
void std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator >::__push_back_slow_path(unsigned short&&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
void std::__1::vector<short, std::__1::allocator >::__push_back_slow_path(short&&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
void std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator >::__push_back_slow_path<unsigned short const&>(unsigned short const&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator >::allocate(unsigned long) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
void std::__1::vector<MABezierPoint, std::__1::allocator >::__push_back_slow_path<MABezierPoint const&>(MABezierPoint const&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
void std::__1::vector<Vector4, std::__1::allocator<Vector4 > >::__push_back_slow_path<Vector4 const&>(Vector4 const&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
void std::__1::vector<Vector4, std::__1::allocator<Vector4 > >::__push_back_slow_path<Vector4 >(Vector4&&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
...
"std::__1::__vector_base_common::__throw_out_of_range() const", referenced from:
MATriangulator::MAPolygonTriangulator::computeTriangles(std::__1::vector<Vector3, std::__1::allocator<Vector3 > >&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
MATriangulator::MAPolygonTriangulator::classifyVertex(int) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
MATriangulator::MAPolygonTriangulator::isEarTip(int) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)
MAGradientColoredLine::MALineBuilder::determineColors(std::__1::vector<Vector3, std::__1::allocator<Vector3 > >*, std::__1::vector<Vector4, std::__1::allocator<Vector4 > >*, std::__1::vector<unsigned short, std::__1::allocator >*, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator >&, std::__1::vector<Vector4, std::__1::allocator<Vector4 > >&) in MAMapKit(MAMapKit-arm64-master.o)

How should I solve this problem